# How does Class.forName(..) work, detailed?

Tags: java, reflection

First of all, I know that `Class.forName()` load a specific class to classloader and call it's static initializers. But, not long ago I found a problem in my company's application, we use some Http Client which call every http request `Class.forName(...)`, that's cause problems during peaks of load. It locks hundreds of threads in monitor inside `forName(...)`.

Here is the picture of my threads, they all waiting monitor!!!

[image]
So, here is my questions:

1. Is it scan classpath and all jars inside web application? (can it be a long operation?)
2. Is it scan every call or if the class already loaded - it doesn't scan classpath?

Comment: You could always trawl through the source code at runtime with your debugger. I don't think that reflection is ever particularly quick, but that's all relative.

Comment: I think your question is **way** too broad. This very much depends on the exact products you are using, which JVM, which version of that, ... in other words: you would have to give a really specific question "what does my product X do on platform Y in that version?" ... but in general; you are correct: using `forName()` indiscriminately sounds like a pretty poor solution. The "default" class loader does do certain caching; so it remembers all loaded classes. But again: we have **no** idea what class loader is running in your environment. So how should we know hat it does?!

Comment: In other words: your question reads like "I have a car. The engine gives strange noises. Whats the problem"? Nobody can answer that from such a deescription. Really. Nobody. Not even Jon Skeet.

Comment: @GhostCat you're right. We made some workaround to avoid this calls.
But, my specs:
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14, mixed mode)
Java: version 1.8.0_111, vendor Oracle Corporation
ClassLoader class: org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader

Comment: I'm skeptical that `Class.forName()` is your problem. It might be expensive the first time it's called for a given value, but it shouldn't be (too) expensive after that. That said, as GhostCat mentioned depending on your specific circumstances (which you haven't shared) it's entirely *possible*.

Comment: @dimo414 I think, it can be expensive. In my case - i don't have suitable class at cp, and each request the client tries to find it.

Comment: Well going off what you've shared in the question there's no way for us to tell...